# Convert a COUNTIF range recorded in an Excel macro to a variable range

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I'm looking for help converting a `COUNTIF` range recorded in an Excel macro to a variable range. I am using Excel VBA to manipulate a monthly file which has a variable amount of records each month.

I recorded a macro to modify and filter the records and was able to convert most of the ranges to variable ranges with the help of this site. However, I am struggling with converting the range to a variable range for the `COUNTIF` function shown below which identifies the duplicated `ID`s in column A with a color. The column is then filtered by the color.

```
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7977,A2)>=2"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
Range(“A1”).Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range(“$A$1:$P$7977”).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255,255,0),Operator:=xlFilter Cell Color
```

Comment: Hi. Please, describe the problem. Then we might help with something.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function that will help you find the last row of the column. See below:

```
Function GetLastRow(sht As Worksheet, col as String) As Integer
    GetLastRow = sht.Range(col & CStr(sht.Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).row
End Function
```

Call this function in every place you need to put the end of your range, with the name of the sheet, and the letter of the column as parameters. See below for how it might work:

```
"=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$" & GetLastRow(Sheets("Sheet1"),"A") & ",A2)>=2"
```